# Is the encryption of a hash a good MAC?

Tags: encryption, hash, mac

At university we were told that it is a bad idea to implement a MAC by simply concatenating a key with the data to sign and to run it through a hash function (e.g. $s = \mathrm{hash}(k||\mathrm{data})$ or $s = \mathrm{hash}(\mathrm{data}||k)$). The next ideas that were presented then were HMAC and CBC-MAC which are a lot more complex (but standardized).

Now I'm wondering what the security of the following "idea" would be (I'm sure that there a good reasons why it is not used as it is more simple than HMAC or CBC-MAC):

1. Compute the hash value $h = \mathrm{hash}(\mathrm{data})$.
2. Compute the ciphertext $c = \mathrm{enc}_k(h) = \mathrm{enc}_k(\mathrm{hash}(\mathrm{data}))$.
3. Set signature $s = c$.

Where $\mathrm{hash}$ is an arbitrary hash function and $\mathrm{enc}$ an arbitrary, symmetric block cipher using a key $k$.

I was not able to find any statements about such schemes, maybe I searched in the wrong place. However, it would be nice if you could help me with that question.

Comment: It certainly has worse properties compared to HMAC, thanks to low collision resistance of this scheme. In particular 128 bit MACs which are fine with HMAC, are too weak with your scheme.

Comment: You're also relying on the strength of the cipher for both encryption and authentication, so given a non-key-disclosing attack on the block cipher you could also inject packets. With HMAC you'd only be able to read the stream unless you could recover the key.

Comment: Note that hash(k||data) is secure for the next generation of hash functions, including all SHA-3 finalists.

Comment: I would also question whether HMAC is considerably more complex that the present idea.  Is $Hash( K_1 | Hash (K_2 | Data))$ really more complex than $Encrypt( Hash( Data ))$?

Comment: i have a question. If my MAC is MAC = enc(hash(m)) with hash = SHA-256 and enc = AES in CBC operation mode, then is it a secure MAC?

Answer (score 16):

No, in general, this is not secure, unless you make additional assumptions on the encryption method beyond the standard assumption of privacy.

To simplify things a bit, the assumption of privacy means that given a ciphertext $C$, the attacker has no information about what the plaintext might be.  However, in your case, we don't really care if the attacker can figure out what the plaintext of the encryption function; we also give him the data, and he can compute $hash(data)$ himself, should he care to.

What we are concerned with is (again, to simplify a bit) that an attacker, given a message M and a valid tag for that message, cannot come up with another message, and a valid tag for that message.  Translating that into your proposal, if the attacker was given $M$, and $E(Hash(M))$, can he pick another message $M'$, and come up with $E(Hash(M'))$?

Well, for a lot of encryption methods, he can.  For example, if we consider a block cipher in [counter mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29), well, if you flip a bit in the ciphertext, the corresponding bit in the plaintext also flips.  What that means that if the attacker computes $E(Hash(M)) \oplus Hash(M) \oplus Hash(M')$, well, that turns out to be precisely $E(Hash(M'))$, and so the attacker has won.

The additional property that we need to assume for the encryption method is nonmalleability; that is, given $M$ and the corresponding encryption $E(M)$, the attacker cannot modify the encryption so that it decrypts to any other specific message.

Of the standard encryption modes, well, [ECB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) actually is nonmalleable, if (and this is a big if) the hash fits entirely within a single block output.  Given that 128 bit hashes are vulnerable to collisions (and a hash collision would be another way of producing a forgery), this means using a nonstandard block cipher (for example, Rijndael with a 256 bit block size).

Authenticated encryption modes are also nonmalleable.  However, this may be considered cheating; authenticated encryption modes work by effectively using a MAC internally; if the point of the exercise is to create a crypto primitive from other crypto primitives, well, this didn't do it.

Comment: But what if I encrypt a 256 bit hash with a 128 bit block-sized block cipher in CBC mode? Any change to the first (plain/ciphertext) block would corrupt the second one. However the second one could be modified without effecting the first one. There is a simple solution for this. Instead of storing the raw first part of the hash, the first plaintext block could be simply be XORed with the second one. So every change to the second one would corrupt the first one. This might be extended further (though I'm not sure right now). Would this work?

Comment: Just noticed @pasgabriele asked a similar question in 2013 but I guess my version might (or might not) be more secure.

Comment: Alright, I'm not 100% sure but there might be a problem with this: with CBC a one bit change to the first ciphertext block would only create a one bit change in the second one's plaintext, however, using [PCBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Propagating_Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28PCBC.29) might improve that..

Comment: I posted a [separate question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25792/24458) to evaluate this technique in a more general way.

Comment: @cooky451: I believe you're misunderstand what I'm trying to say; we have $Mac = E(Hash(M))$, can the attacker find a second message, MAC pair for which $Mac' = E(Hash(M'))$.  It's not the valid sender which is trying to generate $E(Hash(M'))$, it's an attacker. Unless the attacker is forced to modify the $IV$ when he modifies $M$, he (unlike the valid sender) has no issue with reusing an IV.

Comment: @cooky451: why would it fail?  What if the attacker intercepted the original $(M, Mac)$, so the receiver never got it, and replaced it with $(M', Mac')$?

Comment: @poncho Hm, you are completely right, I was too focused on another specific case where it wouldn't work.

Comment: @poncho What breaks if a 256 (or more) bit hashcode is encrypted with a 128-bit block cipher in ECB mode? Unlike CTR mode this does not allow an attacker to modify an encrypted hashcode to decrypt to a specific plaintext, only to scramble 128-bit blocks of the plaintext. A collision attack on the hash requires the full hashcode to match. There's no such thing as a collision attack on a block cipher, which is a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: @JanKanis: to break it, you would look for three messages $M_1, M_2, M_3$ that hash to $(A, B), (B, C), (C, D)$ (where $A, B, C, D$ are 128 bit blocks) - then, you would have them MAC $M_1$ and $M_3$ (and then you'd know the MAC for $M_2$.  According to some BOTE calculations, such a triple of messages is likely to occur after circa $2^{85}$ messages or so (and since the sole computation the attacker would need to perform is on the messages, he can do that himself).  I don't know if there's an efficient way to find such a triple, but if there is, that gives a $O(2^{85})$ attack...

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that this *is* actually secure, up to the length of the block cipher, if $\mathrm{enc}(\cdot)$ is a secure block cipher (a pseudorandom permutation) and if $\mathrm{hash}(\cdot)$ is collision-resistant.

However, there is a catch.  (You just knew there had to be one, didn't you?)

The catch is that typical block ciphers have too narrow of a block width for this to be adequately secure.  In other words, the catch arises when you try to work out quantitative security level  afforded by this construction.

For instance, let's say you use AES as your $\mathrm{enc}(\cdot)$ and SHA1 truncated to 128 bits (to match AES's 128-bit block width) as your $\mathrm{hash}(\cdot)$.  Well, then you only get 64-bit security.  This is vulnerable to collision-finding attacks of complexity approximately $2^{64}$.  After examining about $2^{64}$ messages, you expect to find a pair of messages $m,m'$ such that $\mathrm{hash}(m) = \mathrm{hash}(m')$, through a simple birthday argument.

To be secure against such attacks, you'd need a hash function and block cipher whose block width is at least 160 bits.  But few modern block ciphers support such a block width -- and this was especially the case when HMAC was defined.

Therefore, HMAC is a better fit for the common primitives typically available today.

---

There is a second reason why HMAC was defined.  HMAC was designed to be robust: to minimize the assumptions it makes about the hash function.  In particular, the HMAC construction was designed so that HMAC would have a chance of remaining a secure MAC construction, even if someone happens to discover collision attacks on the hash function.

This turned out to be a prescient design strategy.  For instance, MD5-HMAC was widely used -- and then folks discovered feasible collision attacks on MD5.  Fortunately, despite the fact that the collision-resistance of MD5 is totally broken, MD5-HMAC still appears to be secure: no one knows a way to break it.  So, the designers of HMAC were pretty successful in making the HMAC construction resilient to certain kinds of failures of the hash function.

In contrast, your construction does not have that kind of resilience.  This is a second reason why one might prefer HMAC over your construction.