# Simply message authentication

Tags: authentication

Securing and authenticating messages is easy thanks to computers. Lately I've been thinking about something like Vigenère cipher with a OTP, how secure it is, and how easy it is to implement without the aid of computers. However, one thing it doesn't provide is any authentication. Decrypting a Vigenère cipher with pen and paper is trivial, but hand calculating HMAC-SHA256 is not something I'd like to attempt. Are there any authentication schemes which are simple; easy to compute without the aid of a computer? Any chance any of those schemes actually provide decent security?

Comment: [The answer here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71623/pen-and-paper-authentication) might be of some interest.

Comment: [Also this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/31063/18298)

Comment: Are there any parts in your question that are not answered in the first link provided, Chris_F? If so, please try and focus your answer on those parts. As it stands it very much looks like a dupe to me.