# Strange MAC algorithm

Tags: mac, protocol-analysis

I'm working with a payment provider which uses the following algorithm for signing messages:

1. The merchant is securely given a secret key `k`, known to them and the payment provider only. 
   **EDIT:** Usually the key is quite long.
2. The payment is implemented by using a redirect, and the merchant later receives callbacks containing information about the success or failure of the payment operation. The merchant considers this information trustworthy. Here is an example of a successful payment callback for order no. 1234 and a merchant hosted at `example.com`:

   `example.com?orderID=1234&paymentStatus=SUCCESS&...&signature=abcd`
3. The message `m` which is signed is formed in the following way:

   `orderid=<..>|paymentStatus=<..>|...`
4. The signature algorithm `S(m,k)` is chosen to be: `signature=H(m||k)` (`m||k` means `m` concatenated with the secret key `k`) where `H` is a hashing function, in this case `MD5`.
5. The verification algorithm is `V(signature, m, k)` and returns true only if `H(m||k) = signature`.

As far as I understood the inner workings of MD5 if the signing algorithm was `S(m,k) = H(k||m)` then this would be totally insecure because if an attacker knows `H(k||m)` she may be able to calculate `H(k||m||m')` where `m'` is a message of her choice - this would mean that the signature is vulnerable to both existential and selective forgery. Correct? But deliberately or not the algorithm is `S(m,k) = H(m||k)` - the key is put last in the concatenated string.

So far I cannot think of exploitable vulnerability in this protocol (I'm not considering the problems inherent to MD5). Any ideas, is this secure enough?

Comment: Somewhat related to this [question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2669/555). $\;$ Independently: knowing `MD5(k||m)` allows computing `MD5(k||m||m'||m")` for `m'` a certain known function of `m` and the length of `k` (with `m'` at least 9 bytes or 65 bits), and freely chosen `m"`.

Comment: In short this would be relatively safe unless the message m allows a lot of freedom. In that case you would have to worry (immediately) about the security of MD5. Using HMAC or SHA-3 would fix both the length extension as well as the MD5 related attacks on the MAC (if we just focus on the MAC anyway, I have no idea about the security of the rest of the protocol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can attack the MAC defined by: `MAC(k,m)=MD5(m||k)`, in a chosen-messages setup, basically because MD5's collision-resistance is broken.

The adversary chooses `m` and `m'` of the same length $b\ge64$ bytes, differing only in their first $\lfloor b/64\rfloor$ 64-byte blocks, such that there is a collision after hashing these blocks of `m` and `m'`. If follows that `MAC(k,m)=MAC(k,m')`, and also `MAC(k,m||m")=MAC(k,m'||m")` for any `m"`. We know various efficient techniques to create such `m` and `m'`, with $b$ down to 128 or even 64 bytes, including with a moderate degree of constraints:

- Xiaoyun Wang, Dengguo Feng, Xuejia Lai, Hongbo Yu: *Collisions for Hash Functions MD4, MD5, HAVAL-128 and RIPEMD* (rump session of Crypto 2004, and [in Cryptology ePrint Archive](http://eprint.iacr.org/2004/199))
- Xiaoyun Wang, Hongbo Yu: *How to Break MD5 and Other Hash Functions* ([in proceedings of Eurocrypt 2005](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11426639_2))
- Vlastimil Klima: *Tunnels in Hash Functions: MD5 Collisions Within a Minute* ([in Cryptology ePrint Archive, 2006](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/105))
- Marc Stevens: *Single-block collision attack on MD5* ([in Cryptology ePrint Archive, 2012](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/040), and [here](http://marc-stevens.nl/research/md5-1block-collision/) with code and example)
- Tao Xie, Fanbao Liu and Dengguo Feng: *Fast Collision Attack on MD5* ([in Cryptology ePrint Archive, 2013](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/170))

---

If instead of MD5 we had an unbroken [Merkle-Damgård](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) hash like SHA-256, or a hash secure in the random oracle model (which SHA-256 is not quite, for it has the length-extension property), then we'd basically have no known attack, as discussed in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2669/555).

Answer (score 3):

In general (without talking about MD5): 
Suppose our hashfunction $H$ is a [Merkle-Damgard construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) using a [Davies-Meyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_compression_function#Davies.E2.80.93Meyer) compression function $h=(H_i,m)=E_{m_i}(H_{i-1})\oplus H_{i-1}$. Since the compression function is public, everybody is able to compute the input to the final round of the MD-Hash. In addition, if you know the input to the final round of the compression function, lets call it $H(m)$, you're able to invert the $\oplus$ in the Davies-Meyer construction. This means that the "secret" part of this MAC can be reduced to $E_{k}(H(m))$ which is nothing else than an encrypted hash. So the general answer can be linked to the question [is E(H(m)) a good MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3229/is-the-encryption-of-a-hash-a-good-mac?).