# Would this method deliver a perfectly non-malleable encryption for at least two blocks?

Tags: block-cipher, malleability

*Disclaimer: the algorithms I present here (and in other messages) are used as a hands-on way to learn about developing crypto algorithms, (and might also be of interest for other curious people), not for practical use (at least not after dozens of iterations and peer-review). I understand some people vote down not just because it seems unproved and speculative, and possibly flawed, but also perhaps because I'm not necessarily presenting it this way. This is just a manner of speech. Most of this *is* probably flawed, but that's the whole point here!*

Say I’m using a 128 bit block cipher and would like to encrypt a 256 bit input that would be divided to two blocks, however I wish that every bit changed in the ciphertext would completely corrupt both plaintext blocks when decrypted.

Consider the following simple solution:

---

**Version 1 - two blocks only** (*very flawed - kept for historical reference*)

**Encryption:**

1. XOR the first plaintext block with the second one and store the result in place of the first ciphertext block.
2. Encrypt the two blocks with [PCBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Propagating_Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28PCBC.29) mode, meaning both the first block’s plaintext and ciphertext are XORed with the second block’s plaintext before encrypting.

**Decryption:**

1. Decrypt the two ciphertext blocks with PCBC mode.
2. XOR the first plaintext block with the second and store the result in place of the first.

Will this method deliver true non-malleability?

What about an extended version with more than two blocks? - in which during encryption, the additional processing simply goes from the last block backwards, XORs with the subsequent block and stores the result in place (the processing during decryption is also simple, i think). I read though that with PCBC *"if two adjacent ciphertext blocks are exchanged, this does not affect the decryption of subsequent blocks."* so I'm not sure it would deliver its promise in this case.

---

**Version 2 - two blocks only** (*reformulated to overcome issues pointed out by @poncho but still flawed - kept for historical reference*).

**Encryption:**

1. XOR the first plaintext block with the IV and the second plaintext block and store the result in place of the first plaintext block.
2. Encrypt the first plaintext block twice, with two different keys (where the second key may be derived from the first).
3. Output the first encryption of the first block as the first ciphertext block.
4. XOR the second plaintext block with the second encryption of the first block (note the second encryption is completely secret and will never be known).
5. Encrypt the XORed second block and output it.

**Decryption:**

1. Decrypt the first ciphertext block.
2. Re-encrypt the resulting plaintext of the first block with the secondary key (note the resulting plaintext is still XORed with the IV and original second plaintext block).
3. Decrypt the second ciphertext block.
4. XOR the resulting plaintext with the re-encryption of the first block and store it in place.
5. XOR the first block with the IV and decrypted second block and store it in place.

[TODO: consider if this could be extended to more than 2 blocks - the "pre-processing stage" is explained in the remarks of the first version of the algorithm]

**NOTE: this still needs some work, it has a serious problem!**

Assume an IV of 0, and both plaintext blocks of 0: corrupting on bit of the second ciphertext block would give out a completely psuedorandom second plaintext block, XOR it with the second encryption of the first decrypted block to get the final value of the second, now XORing with the first would yield the exact same value for the two blocks! So right now it does propagate errors backwards, but doesn't deliver true non-malleability. I'll try to see how to fix that tomorrow..

A possible sketch of a solution is to try to a create a dependency for the first block on a *psuedorandom permutation* of the second one rather than on its plain value. Hopefully that can be done without introducing an additional encryption step. We'll see about that..

---

**Version 3 - two blocks only** - (*corrects the flaw in the second one, modified in-place to overcome flaws pointed out by @Ricky Demer - might be correct*)

**Encryption:**

*Derive intermediate blocks* $I_1,I_2$:
$I_1 = P_1 \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus P_2)$
$I_2 = P_2 \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1)$

*Derive ciphertext blocks* $C_1,C_2$:
$C_1 = E_{key_1}(I_1)$
$C_2 = E_{key_1}(I_2)$

**Decryption:**

*Derive intermediate blocks* $I_1,I_2$:
$I_1 = D_{key_1}(C_1)$
$I_2 = D_{key_1}(C_2)$

*Derive plaintext blocks* $P_1,P_2$:
$P_2 = I_2 \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1)$
$P_1 = I_1 \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus P_2)$

---

**An initial attempt for handling the general case for $n$ blocks** (*based on the same technique as the previous one - but flawed for $n>2$*)

**Encryption**:

For every plaintext block $P_k, k \leq n$

Derive an intermediate block:
$I_k = P_k \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1 \oplus I_2 \oplus ... \oplus I_{k-1} \oplus P_{k+1})$
(where the last block would be $I_n = P_n \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1 \oplus I_2 \oplus ... \oplus I_{n-1})$)

Encrypt the intermediate block:
$C_k = E_{key_1}(I_k)$

**Decryption**:

Go forward and decrypt all the intermediate blocks with the first key:

For every ciphertext block $C_k, k \leq n$
$I_k = D_{key_1}(C_k)$

Now start at $n$ and go backwards to derive the plaintext blocks:

Derive the last plaintext block:
$P_n = I_n \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1 \oplus I_2 \oplus ... \oplus I_{n-1})$
For every intermediate block $I_k, k < n$:
$P_k = I_k \oplus E_{key_2}(IV \oplus I_1 \oplus I_2 \oplus ... \oplus I_{k-1} \oplus P_{k+1})$

**Note:** This is vulnerable to block-exchanging attacks, since during decryption the intermediate blocks are XORed before encryption, and the XOR operation is commutative. I'm considering different solutions:

- A simple but impractical solution would be to use a different key for each block (i.e. one key per index).
- A faster one would be to XOR the current intermediate block with a hash of all the previous ones before encrypting it to the ciphertext, i.e. $C_k = E_{key_1}(I_k \oplus H(I_1..I_{k-1}))$ and reverse the operation during decryption. Since the intermediate blocks are in essence secret, encrypted, psuedo-random data, the hash used probably doesn't need to be cryptographic (e.g. perhaps CRC32/64 could suffice) and could be calculated incrementally, giving a relatively small impact on performance.
- An even more interesting (but speculative and possibly flawed) solution is not to use decryption at all but to use the block cipher in something akin to counter mode with a different nonce for each block for the outward encryption, where the nonce would be the XOR of all the previously decrypted blocks. The *decryption* of the ciphertext would be something like $I_k = C_k \oplus E_{key_1}(IV \oplus I_1 \oplus I_2 \oplus ... \oplus I_{k-1})$. This may actually imply a total reformulation and simplification of the whole algorithm.

---

**Version 4**: (*A new approach, completely reformulated to prevent block exchange attacks. In development - might be flawed at its current state*)

Note: for convenience, the IV is considered to be the 0th intermediate block, i.e. $I_0 = IV$

**Encryption**:

*For all non-final plaintext blocks* $P_k, 1 \le k < n$

Derive a non-final intermediate block $I_k$:
$I_k = P_k \oplus E(I_{k-1} \oplus P_{k+1} \oplus E(I_0))$
Derive a non-final ciphertext block $C_k$:
$C_k = I_k \oplus E(I_{k-1})$

*For the final plaintext block* $P_n$:

Derive a final intermediate block $I_n$:
$I_n = P_n \oplus E(I_{n-1})$
Derive a final ciphertext block $C_n$:
$C_n = E(I_n)$

**Decryption**:

*Iterate forward to derive intermediate blocks*:

Derive all non-final intermediate blocks $I_k, 1 \le k < n$:
$I_k = C_k \oplus E(I_{k-1})$
Derive the final intermediate block $I_n$:
$I_n = D(C_n)$

*Iterate backwards to derive plaintext blocks*:

Derive the final plaintext block $P_n$:
$P_n = I_n \oplus E(I_{n-1})$
Derive all non-final plaintext blocks $P_k, 1 \le k < n$:
$P_k = I_k \oplus E(I_{k-1} \oplus P_{k+1} \oplus E(I_0))$

The approach here is a bit more subtle. The outer encryption XORs the current intermediate block with the encryption of the previous one. This means that during the forward iterating part of the decryption process, the first corrupted ciphertext block would actually render the underlying intermediate block *malleable*, since changing one bit of its corresponding ciphertext block would only change one bit of it. The next ones would be randomly corrupted though, since they depend on an encryption of the previous ones. This is not a real issue though, since during the backwards stage it would be *corrupted again*, this time randomly since the next plaintext block would not be the expected one.

(*There are currently some minor issues with the similarity of the inner and outer encryption, especially for the cases where the plaintext is 0. I'm looking for ways to get around that [without using two different keys]. The current solution is to XOR the inner encryption arguments with the constant value $E(I_0)$ as a secret random constant (per IV) to avoid situations where both the inner and outer will yield the same result and cancel each other - this doesn't require an additional encryption operation since it is needed anyway by the outer encryption. I'm also considering adding a counter if that would prove necessary*)

The following diagram describes the encryption process (For $n=3$. The two layers have been separated for clarity, but it should be understood that the whole process occurs in one forward pass):

[image: Encryption diagram]

This one describes the two-stage decryption process (also for $n=3$).

[image: Decryption diagram]

**NOTE:** *this is a work in progress, and might contain severe or careless mistakes.. It is very preliminary and there is still much to analyze - the scrutiny of the community is needed and strongly appreciated.*

*In case this algorithm does, at some point, evolve to a correct algorithm (though in the special case of $n \le 2$ it might already be at its current state), it would be published under [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/).*

Comment: It looks like your third version requires 4 encryptions per block, 2 with each key. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer Since there are a total of two blocks involved here so I think it actually might be two per block (my assertion of 3 was probably incorrect). Anyway I'm considering how to completely reformulate it again, I think it could be made simpler. Perhaps I need to start treating the IV as the "previous" block on the chain, as this could be extended further to more than two blocks.

Comment: You should also note that if 128 is large, then there is a simple&standard way to do the no-ciphertext-expansion version of what you're trying for, although it's slightly less efficient than your third version. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: I would definitely look at other algorithms but first I want to finish this one.

Comment: Now that I'm actually looking at your decryption procedure, I see that your scheme is very malleable, $\hspace{.13 in}$ since xoring the IV with any string will xor the result of decryption with the same string. $\hspace{1.19 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Yes, that is something I'm thinking about. I guess that IV should be treated as the previous intermediate block, so it should be encrypted as well (just like is done for the second block) . That why I probably initially guessed it would take 3 encryptions per block (though in this particular case, the second one is last one and it doesn't have any successor so only two encryptions are needed for it)

Comment: @RickyDemer I modified the algorithm, thanks for your input, it is very valuable!

Comment: The version you have at the moment (you might still be editing) is still malleable because changing $\hspace{.42 in}$ the IV would change block1 of the decryption result but not block2 of the decryption result. $\hspace{.92 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer $I_1 = P_1 \oplus E_{k_2}(IV) \oplus E_{k_2}(P_2)$  ,  
$I_2 = P_2 \oplus E_{k_2}(I_1)$ - The second block includes the propagation of the IV through the intermediate block. What I am considering though is whether the IV and the next plaintext block could be simply XORed and encrypted together instead of encrypting them separately.

Comment: "The second block" of the _ciphertext_ "includes the propagation ... intermediate block". $\:$ "The second block" of the _plaintext_ is not affected by the IV. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer great feedbak! I'm still not 100% clear on this but I guess there are several ways to overcome this. A trivial one would simply be to XOR I1 with the IV before encrypting it for the second intermediate block. This means that in the case of more than 2 blocks it would have to XOR with a cumulative XOR of all the previously decrypted blocks. I'll take some time to figure this out before I make any change (BTW I [somewhat hastily] made the change I considered in my previous message, hopefully it doesn't break anything)

Comment: @RickyDemer I've made the changes, but now I'm considering an attack that would swap the IV and first ciphertext block -> at that case, right now, the second block would still decrypt to the same value.. I'm thinking about how to overcome this..

Comment: @RickyDemer A possible solution would be to use a very fast, non-cryptographically secure random number generator, seed it with a secret constant value, and then XOR its output _in order_ with the IV and the previous intermediate blocks before encrypting (essentially "upgrading" the XOR operation to an non-commutative one). A simpler solution might also be possible.

Comment: @RickyDemer OK, I now realize that might not be needed. I forgot that It's XORing with the intermediate (decrypted) blocks and not the ciphertext. So swapping the IV with the first block would actually decrypt the IV first - to basically a garbage value and take the first block's ciphertext as the IV. But I guess still need to keep an eye, in general, on swapping attacks.

Comment: $I_2 = P_2 \oplus H(IV), I_1 = P_1 \oplus H( I_2)$  Now encrypt $I_1, I_2$ using the IV and CBC mode.  $H()$ could be $E_k, D_k, HMAC_k$, or just an unkeyed hash, e.g. SHA-256 (take top 128 bits if hash output is longer).  Can be easily extended to more blocks.

Comment: Sorry, PCBC mode, so any change propagates to the end (which then propagates back to the beginning).

Comment: You keep re-mixing in the IV in all your versions, I don't think that's necessary.  Your 4th version, all of the encryptions except the final block-by-block one are still acting as hashes, they don't need to be encryptions.  It might be easier to think of if you don't overload what you're using E for.  THEN analyze whether using $E_k$ as your hashing function causes any security problems.

Comment: Now that you're doing two additional encryptions/hashes before the final encryption, simply doing a forward/backward mixing pass seems more straightforward. Using your $P_0 = IV$, $I_k = P_k \oplus H(I_{k-1})$ (for $0 \le k \le n$),
$J_k = I_k \oplus H(I_{k+1})$ (for $0 \le k \lt n$),
$C_k = E(J_k)$ (for $0 \le k \le n$, $C_0$ is the transmitted IV)

Comment: @StevePeltz Thanks for your input, really appreciated. I'm aware many of the encryption operations could also be replaced by hashes. One of the requirements I set to myself (I guess I haven't really mentioned it though) is to only depend on encryption operations, and not to expand over the size of the plaintext. Using hashing one can use a simpler system than this one ,as a hash would allow to work on more than one block at a time - though I haven't spent much time the best way that could be done. (BTW another advantage of encryption is that in many platforms today it's faster than hashing)

Comment: @StevePeltz If by re-mixing the IV you mean the way I use $E(I_0)$ (calculated only once, as I explained in the notes) in the 4th version. That is only used as a sort of  "nonce" to make similar operations in the outer and inner layers have different results. The previous approach was to use different keys. This is a relatively "technical" issue I guess, because it doesn't look like something that would be impossible to fix with simple tricks. It's more important for me to verify and even prove the correctness of the algorithm first.

Comment: Using the general form of a hash rather than a specific encryption, all that adding an XOR of a constant does is change the hash function.  If you show that your construct holds for any hash function with certain properties, then mixing in the IV each time is no longer necessary, you've simply created a new hash function $H'(x) = H(x \oplus K)$.  You can still use $E_k$ or $D_k$ for the hash (with the same key or a different key).

Comment: Well, I think I might have gave a somewhat false impression by saying I'm thinking about "proving" its correctness. I don't think I have the theoretical knowledge and understanding for that. My approach (and motivation) to algorithms mostly pragmatic.  I guess probably not the kind that's suitable for a cryptographer (I'm not even a CS person, at all..) I think mostly about simplicity and performance.. The reason I added the constant was simply as a "hack" because $I_k = P_k \oplus E(I_{k-1} \oplus P_{k+1})$  when $P_{k+1}$ was zero would simply cancel out $C_k = I_k \oplus E(I_{k-1})$ :).

Comment: @StevePeltz BTW if I didn't constrain myself to use only encryption and did use a hash: My initial (possibly flawed) approach would probably do the following: XOR each plaintext block with the next one before encryption (the encryption mode could be CBC I guess). Calculate a hash of all ciphertext blocks except the last and then XOR the last plaintext block with that hash before encrypting it. Decrypt backwards and the errors should propagate backwards. Note this is a really initial sketch. My experience with this shows even things that look initially good might not eventually prove correct.

Comment: @StevePeltz Just realized, of course, that's flawed, because the errors do propagate backwards but not as psuedorandom values (that's an early error I made in some of my previous versions). So some other way might be needed (hopefully without resorting to another encryption layer). I'm really not into this right now (too concentrated on the encryption-only approach). Maybe later, when I finish with this one..

Comment: @StevePeltz It's perhaps possible to "fix" that flawed approach by XORing the blocks before encryption, instead of with the next plaintext block but with a fast, non-cryptographic hash of it. The point here is not to avoid collisions or authenticate anything, but to propagate psuedorandom "garbage", any type of it (the corrupted last block would serve as a high quality "seed"). The "outer" hash would probably do need to be cryptographic I guess. I'm not sure if this solution is up to the standards of modern cryptography though, I'll leave that for the experts :).

Comment: @StevePeltz I implicitly also assumed here the crypto-hash would be also applied the key/IV of course (could even be an HMAC). Otherwise since the adversary would know the expected hash (even though its encrypted, it's applied to the ciphertext ) and since they can predict the resulting plaintext (assuming the plaintext or at least the last part of it is known) they could manipulate (at least some) of the resulting (garbage) plaintext by creating targeted modifications to the ciphertext (though that wouldn't be very easy..).

Comment: @StevePeltz Another interesting option is instead of using an fast hash, use a fast, non-cryptographic RNG. Use the last plaintext block as the RNG seed and XOR all plaintext blocks with its output before encryption (done backwards - from last to first). I think this might be easier to prove correctness on and should be more secure, since even if the RNG gives out one result at position k that's equal to the existing one that was XORed with, this wouldn't create any chain reaction for the previous ones. Perhaps I'll post this on as a different answer (I'll need to think it through first)

Comment: @StevePeltz I posted this idea as another answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've ever seen a question to which 43 edits have been applied (yet).....

Comment: @StevePeltz In my RNG answer here I accidentally came across a potential, general way to perform authenticated encryption using only a single encryption operation per block (and has noting to do with using an RNG). It might be flawed at its current state (I haven't really found any problem at this point) but even then there could still be a possibility it could be fixed. I posted a [separate question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25891/24458) for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Crypto.SE is not the place to develop a new cryptographic algorithm.

Comment: @cpast I think you're being too harsh on this. Since the people here are very knowledgeable it would be a useful place to do just that. Flawed techniques and ideas would be identified quickly (compared to just any other place), quickly ending the discussion and giving a good benefit and a learning experience to everyone involved. I don't think there's much harm done . The last days were sort of intense, and I did make a lot of edits (but it was all within a single question). It relaxed a bit today.

Comment: @cpast, Would it be OK to "develop" algorithms by making always new questions? So v1 would get it's own question, v2 would get it's own  and would be improved based on the flaws found in v1,...

Comment: @SOJPM At a bare minimum, that would be better. This "question" doesn't really have an answer, because Anon keeps changing the question in a way that specifically invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @cpast Are you serious? flooding the website with speculative questions that are not really of interest for most people? (but are for some, see for example Steve Peltz who seem to got very interested) I guess might be banned for that? (BTW and I probably should change my name from "anon" at some point - it was a temporary name but then I found out I can only change it every month).

Comment: @Anon I am serious. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. As it stands, this isn't *a* question, it's several different ones.

Comment: @StevePeltz The original authenticated encryption idea was flawed (simply a blunder, I didn't see the obvious fault, my mind was off), but I posted a different question [using an RNG instead](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25894/24458) that hasn't really got extreme negative criticisms (at least not yet), I would appreciate you took some time to look at it as so far you've been very helpful! (BTW this question (on non-malleability) was voted down purely because the original question was edited many times. I don't think it's fair. But I don't see a point posting it again, at least for now).

Answer (score 1):

> Will this method deliver true non-malleability?

No.  If we set the ciphertext to the value $(B, B)$, then the decrypted plaintext will have the second block as $B$ (assuming that the PCBC mode uses an implicit plaintext/ciphertext IV of 0; if it's two known constants, it's easy to adjust for that).

Even if we ignore this, it also fails to make sure that any change in a ciphertext bit modifies each plaintext bit with probability $\approx 0.5$; if you modify bit $i$ in the first ciphertext block, that will modify bit $i$ in the first plaintext block (with probability 1), and not any other bit in that first plaintext block.

Comment: Thanks, I admit I haven't really figured out your answer at all but first I must ask.. What it you simply rejected equivalent blocks during decryption? (and in general for cases with non-zero IV simply rejected those particular edge cases) and say, used another, derived, key if this extremely rare outcome happened during encryption?

Comment: @Anon2000: how in the world would you be able to decrypt with your suggestion?  If the decryptor got a ciphertext $(A,B)$, how does he guess whether to use the normal method, or whether he should use the derived key?  As for figuring out the answer, well, that's straightforward; start with a ciphertext with two identical blocks, and step through the decrypt process

Comment: Well, I guess with a more constructive approach, I could try to work out the problems (thanks for the feedback!) but I must ask first: Does a non-malleable encryption for more than a single block been mathematically proven impossible? (so I can rest assured this would be fruitless and go for a vacation? :) ) or there exists the possibility something would actually come out of this? (I'm only doing this for fun and learning I guess..)

Comment: Choose random nonce n, set the IV for CBC mode as HMAC(n, m), where m is the entire message, including the nonce and padding.

Comment: @StevePeltz: how would you decrypt?  In any case, I suspect Anon2000 is looking for a mode that doesn't do any ciphertext expansion

Comment: _"if you modify bit i in the first ciphertext block, that will modify bit i in the first plaintext block (with probability 1), and not any other bit in that first plaintext block."_ - My first instinct on how to solve this was not to use PCBC at all but instead propagate a second encryption of the first blocks's plaintext with a second, derived key. This may not be the simplest solution, but I guess we'll start with that.

Comment: @Anon2000, First, as Steven says, you probably should be looking for a MAC.

But if you're really after non-malleable encryption, then what you want is a wide-block cipher, such as EME or the more recent AEZ with a zero-bit tag and zero-bit nonce (http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/aez/).

Comment: @poncho The IV is still sent in the clear as usual.  Decrypt, extract the nonce, verify HMAC(n,m) matches the IV.  You'd need to know the block length ahead of time.  Nonce could be fixed length prepended to the message (so you don't get into messy bits with padding to find the nonce).  If nonce is the size of a block, it's effectively an extended IV (or skip the nonce if semantic security not needed, I guess).  I didn't assume any restrictions on expanding ciphertext, e.g. adding an IV, just that all bits be affected if any changes made to any of the ciphertext.

Comment: I meant message length, or block count, not block length.

Comment: Bleah, I was reading it as any bit changed in the plaintext would modify every bit in the ciphertext, never mind!  Double encrypt, second time with no IV, back to front, including the IV (CBC mode both ways).

Comment: Combine that with what I originally was saying and you have a system where any change to ciphertext changes all of the plaintext, any change to plaintext changes all of the ciphertext.  Embed nonce in message (if needed), IV = H(m); Encrypt with CBC and IV; encrypt again (including IV) in reverse (with no additionall IV).  Decrypt in reverse, then decrypt forward (using decrypted IV), then verify IV = H(m).

Answer (score 0):

Let $H(m)$ be any strong hash function.  Since you want to use encryption only, we'll specify that $H(m)$ = $E_{key}(m)$ where $E$ is a 128-bit block cipher.  We're trying to create an encryption mode that will cause any change to the ciphertext to propagate over all blocks of the plaintext.

Strategy is to do two passes over the message, first forwards, then backwards, using the hashing function to diffuse any changes over the entire message.  Any change to the plaintext (or IV) will change all bits in the ciphertext, any change to the ciphertext (including transmitted IV) will change all bits in the plaintext.

$n$ is the number of blocks in the message.

**Encrypt**
$I_0=IV$
$I_k=P_k \oplus H(I_{k−1})$ (for $0 \lt k \le n$)
$J_n=I_n$
$J_k=I_k \oplus H(I_{k+1})$ (for $0 \le k \lt n$)
$C_k=E_{key}(J_k)$ (for $0 \le k \le n$, $C_0$ is the transmitted IV)

**Decrypt**
$J_k = D_{key}(C_k)$ (for $0 \le k \le n$, $C_0$ is the transmitted IV)
$I_n = J_n$
$I_k = J_k \oplus H(I_{k+1})$ (for $0 \le k \lt n$)
$P_k = I_k \oplus H(I_{k-1})$ (for $0 \lt k \le n$)

The IV is discarded at the end of decryption.  If semantic security isn't needed, set $I_0 = 0$ and don't calculate $J_0$ or $C_0$.

Alternatively, if you set $I_0$ to a constant, or a hash of the entire message, do the rest of the processing normally, then $C_0$ will function as a MAC (verify $I_0$ is the correct value).

If using that form, you can still get semantic security by appending a nonce to the message (perhaps the last 64 bits of the last block, with any padding occurring before the nonce to avoid a padding attack).

When using $H = E_{key}$, the first pass is using the cipher in CFB mode.  Since both passes are keyed, not just hashes, you should be able to skip the third encryption.

Comment: Looks quite straightforward, and that's good because it makes it easy to reason about it. Though I've spent a lot on trying to limit my own approach to only two expensive operations per block. Surprisingly, your idea of iterating backwards during encryption as well didn't occur to me though (even on the previous drafts), probably since I already have a (hopefully correct) solution with only 2 operations per block (which can even be streamed, since it only iterates forward). My solution in the comments required one encrypt, one crypto hash and one fast hash, but may not be up to crypto standard

Comment: $I_0 = H(IV \oplus Key)$ would be cheap and help protect against known- and chosen-plaintext attacks (though known-plaintext would be hard,  it would make it almost impossible, for chosen-plaintext, that would be important, as the plaintext could be set to allow blocks to be swapped.)

Comment: Not sure how that's better than $H(IV)$ or just $I_0 = IV$, especially if $H = E_{key}$.  I'm not sure why I specified $I_0 = H(IV)$ instead of just $I_0 = IV$, I'll change that in the text.

Comment: @Anon2000 I added a note that if H is an encryption function, you should be able to skip the third encryption.

Comment: Say $H$ is an encryption function and the encryption step is skipped, and there is only one plaintext block then $C_1 = P_1 \oplus E(IV)$ - in this case a one bit change in $C_1$ would lead to one bit change in $P_1$. That's the reason I used direct encryption on the last block and on the inner ones XORed the previous intermediate with the next plaintext block before the inner encryption. So as I described in the comments, the first intermediate block is malleable on the the forward pass, but then it gets randomly corrupted on the backwards one (not 100% this is an ultra-precise explanation).

Comment: I meant: the first non-final corrupt intermediate block is malleable on the forward decryption pass, but since it has an internal dependency on a psuedorandom permutation of the next plaintext block. It would get randomly corrupted on the backwards decryption pass. So the forward pass ensures that any error would propagate to the last plaintext block, and the backwards one ensures all the blocks would be randomly corrupted if there was any corruption in the ciphertext (some would be corrupted twice if they are positioned after the first ciphertext block that was corrupted).

Comment: No, the change to $C_1$ changes the value of $I_0$; $I_0 = C_0 \oplus E(C_1)$, $P_1 = C_1 \oplus E(I_0)$.

Comment: Another one of my (implicit) personal constraints was not to require an additional encryption operation for the IV (and have it in plaintext), though it didn't actually occur to me (at any point!) that it could also be set to depend on the next intermediate block(s), so that's an interesting idea! so I guess making that (rather small, especially for larger messages) sacrifice could simplify the algorithm.

Comment: @Anon2000 The last block only gets encrypted once, so you only have one encryption per message block  for each pass.  The IV gets encrypted once, the last block gets encrypted once.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using one encryption, one cryptographic hash and one (possibly fast) non-cryptographic pseudorandom number generator operation per block.

**Encryption:**

1. Take the last plaintext block, and use its value (or some part of it), to seed a (possibly non-cryptographic) random number generator (note it could be XORed with the key for added security, so it would be impossible to guess).
2. XOR all non-final plaintext blocks with the output of the RNG.
3. Encrypt all plaintext blocks except the last in CBC mode (or some other mode that would work..).
4. Use a crypto-hash to calculate $H(Key \oplus IV || C_1 || C_2 || .. || C_{n-1})$ (could use something even more secure like an HMAC, but I gave this as an example)
5. XOR the hash with the last plaintext block before encryption and encrypt it (not required to use CBC mode here).

**Decryption:**

1. Calculate $H(Key \oplus IV || C_1 || C_2 || .. || C_{n-1})$
2. Decrypt the ciphertext.
3. Decrypt the last block and XOR it with the calculated hash.
4. Seed the resulting value to the RNG.
5. XOR all non-final blocks with the output of the RNG.

**Required RNG properties:**

For this to work some properties of the RNG should be ensured (in general, at least these are what I can think of right now):

1. Given two different seeds (one guaranteed to be pseudo-random) it produces a two different pseudorandom sequences of values, that are highly unlikely to contain sub-sequences of each other.
2. Given the output with a given seed, the probability of having a result at position k that's equal the one with given with a different (but psuedorandom) seed is `1/max value` of the RNG (assume the result is integer and the min value is zero).

A nice property of this is that if a MAC is calculated anyway on the chiphertext, this could be used as a relatively cheap addition to make the message non-malleable as well. I'm not sure how much benefit this would give in practice if a MAC is already transmitted with the message, but it's interesting to know it can be done relatively cheaply (if this proves to be secure of course).

---

An attempt at improvement of the previous algorithm to use only one encryption and one non-crypto RNG operation (i.e. without a hash function):

**Encryption:**

1. Take the last plaintext block, and use its value (or some part of it), to seed a random number generator (note it could be XORed with the key for added security, so it would be impossible to guess).
2. XOR all non-final plaintext blocks with the output of the RNG.
3. Encrypt all non-final plaintext blocks in the following way (assuming $C_0 = IV$ and $P_0 = 0$):
   $C_k = P_k \oplus E(P_{k-1})$
4. Encrypt the final block as follows:
   $C_n = E(P_n \oplus P_{n-1})$

**Decryption:**

1. Decrypt all non-final blocks:
   $P_k = C_k \oplus E(P_{k-1})$
2. Decrypt the final block as follows:
   $P_n = D(C_k) \oplus P_{n-1}$
3. Use the last plaintext block to seed the RNG
4. XOR all non-final blocks with the RNG output.

(note: for a weaker RNG maybe $C_n = E(P_n \oplus E(P_{n-1}))$ would have better guarantees on the randomness of the seed)

This was hastily written so I hope this is correct and secure (if not it may be possible to fix it without making it significantly slower), but still need to look into it (haven't deeply considered block exchange attacks, for example). If it is correct it may be faster than my original solution.

Another thing: a nice property of non-malleable encryption, is of course, it can easily be used to create a MAC - just set the last plaintext block to an expected value such as a zero block or some other constant (probably not zeroes in this case as it wouldn't be a good seed to the RNG, perhaps using the key would be an interesting alternative), so this might be a cheap, fast way to both render the massage non-malleable and add a MAC to it (of course, assuming it's correct and secure).

*Note: if this works then the type of encryption mode used here could be used a general, fast way to both encrypt and MAC and the same time (?!!) - without the RNG, i mean?. That seems unreasonable.. I guess I have to analyze this further to verify it's not flawed in some way..*

*Update: I posted [a separate question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/25894/24458) to try to evaluate and scrutinize this method of authenticated encryption, independently of the way it's being used here to achieve non-malleability.*